# How to get now date using a GMT? Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, momentjs

I have a problem, I have to use Moment Timezone but I don't have the string timezone. This is where I need to pick the date: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values
So, I need for example a lib or something that can convert actual date to "(GMT-09:00) Alaska"

Moment Timezone as I know it can convert a date to a specific string timezone like:
`moment.tz("China/Beijing")` but I need something like `moment.xx("(GMT-09:00) Alaska")`

Comment: Hi.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Why Windows display names? Are you making a dropdown list?  Do you have .NET on the back-end or is it all JS?  Also, the "time zone index values" page you linked to is a *very* old support page for Windows Embedded POS 1.1.  Is that really what you are using?  (Modern Windows does not use the index values, but has similar zones which you can output with `tzutil /L` on the command line.)

Comment: Also, `"China/Beijing"` is not a valid IANA time zone identifier.  The correct ID for China is `"Asia/Shanghai"`.  Additionally, Moment and Moment-Timezone shouldn't be used in new projects.  See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: Hi guys, my client wants the field "Time" from the Microsoft Page that I posted, I'm just using Nodejs and not .Net. Another way is create a two dimensions array where I have something like:
`{gmt: "(GMT-04:00) Manaus", timezone: "America/Manaus"}`
But do that one by one is too work, that's why I need a lib or something like that I posted :S

Comment: It's more complex than you are thinking.  There are currently 594 IANA time zone names and 140 Windows time zones.  The string you're asking for is a *Windows Display Name*, and those are localized into different languages (English, French, Chinese, etc.).  Those lists are *dynamic*, as time zones are added or display names or their translations updated.  I maintain [a library](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) that handles these complexities for .NET, but I know of nothing similar for Node.js.  Are you running Node or Windows or Linux? Do the strings only need to match the OS language?

Comment: Also, you would *never* be able to take a Windows Display Name and use it as *input* such as in your `moment.xx("(GMT-09:00) Alaska")` example.  Display names are for human readable output only - not to be used as the identity of a time zone.

Comment: So what choices I have? Right now in the frontend I'm using the timezone list that moment timezone return, it's okay but my client prefeer something more standard like those Microsoft presents on that web I sent. What can I do? I will explain what I'm doing:
- I have a web where the user needs to pick a timezone from a dropdown list, I'm using the names that Moment Timezone return, an array list
- I have a Nodejs backend where I need to convert the actual date to the user timezone , after that I need make a comparison like: if(myConvertedDateHour === customeTimezoneDateHour)

Comment: It depends on what you're doing.  Often, the easiest option is to convert to UTC on the client side, since you don't need them to pick a time zone to do that.  Then you can just compare UTC to UTC, anywhere you need to.  However - this doesn't work well for scheduling appointments.  In that case, you would need to pass a time zone id to the back-end along with the appointment time.  I hear you about the display name. There's nothing like what you're asking for built-in.  I'll give a partial answer below shortly...

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer this from the perspective of creating a drop-down list to select an IANA time zone identifier while showing a Windows display name.

**Caveats:**

- The list below was generated on 2020-09-22.  It may be outdated as time zones are modified or added.
- The list contains the latest Windows time zone display names for the US English (en-US) locale.
- The list represents a one-way reverse mapping from Windows display name, to Windows time zone ID, to the best fitting IANA canonical time zone name.  You can use it for a time zone picker, but you can't use it for an *arbitrary* IANA time zone name.
- The list was built using the .NET [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) library, with the following simple C# program:

```cs
var names = TZNames.GetDisplayNames("en-US", useIanaZoneIds: true);
Console.WriteLine("<select>");
foreach ((string id, string displayName) in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"  <option value=\"{id}\">{displayName}</option>");
}
Console.WriteLine("</select>");
```

Here is the list, as an HTML dropdown:

```
<select>
  <option value="Etc/GMT+12">(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West</option>
  <option value="Etc/GMT+11">(UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11</option>
  <option value="America/Adak">(UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands</option>
  <option value="Pacific/Honolulu">(UTC-10:00) Hawaii</option>
  <option value="Pacific/Marquesas">(UTC-09:30) Marquesas Islands</option>
  <option value="America/Anchorage">(UTC-09:00) Alaska</option>
  <option value="Etc/GMT+9">(UTC-09:00) Coordinated Universal Time-09</option>
  <option value="America/Whitehorse">(UTC-07:00) Yukon</option>
  <option value="America/Tijuana">(UTC-08:00) Baja California</option>
  <option value="Etc/GMT+8">(UTC-08:00) Coordinated Universal Time-08</option>
  <option value="America/Los_Angeles">(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)</option>
  <option value="America/Phoenix">(UTC-07:00) Arizona</option>
  <option value="America/Chihuahua">(UTC-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan</option>
  <option value="America/Denver">(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)</option>
  <option value="America/Guatemala">(UTC-06:00) Central America</option>
  <option value="America/Chicago">(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)</option>
  <option value="Pacific/Easter">(UTC-06:00) Easter Island</option>
  <option value="America/Mexico_City">(UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey</option>
  <option value="America/Regina">(UTC-06:00) Saskatchewan</option>
  <option value="America/Bogota">(UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco</option>
  <option value="America/Cancun">(UTC-05:00) Chetumal</option>
  <option value="America/New_York">(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)</option>
  <option value="America/Port-au-Prince">(UTC-05:00) Haiti</option>
  <option value="America/Havana">(UTC-05:00) Havana</option>
  <option value="America/Indiana/Indianapolis">(UTC-05:00) Indiana (East)</option>
  <option value="America/Grand_Turk">(UTC-05:00) Turks and Caicos</option>
  <option value="America/Asuncion">(UTC-04:00) Asuncion</option>
  <option value="America/Halifax">(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)</option>
  <option value="America/Caracas">(UTC-04:00) Caracas</option>
  <option value="America/Cuiaba">(UTC-04:00) Cuiaba</option>
  <option value="America/La_Paz">(UTC-04:00) Georgetown, La Paz, Manaus, San Juan</option>
  <option value="America/Santiago">(UTC-04:00) Santiago</option>
  <option value="America/St_Johns">(UTC-03:30) Newfoundland</option>
  <option value="America/Araguaina">(UTC-03:00) Araguaina</option>
  <option value="America/Sao_Paulo">(UTC-03:00) Brasilia</option>
  <option value="America/Cayenne">(UTC-03:00) Cayenne, Fortaleza</option>
  <option value="America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires">(UTC-03:00) City of Buenos Aires</option>
  <option value="America/Nuuk">(UTC-03:00) Greenland</option>
  <option value="America/Montevideo">(UTC-03:00) Montevideo</option>
  <option value="America/Punta_Arenas">(UTC-03:00) Punta Arenas</option>
  <option value="America/Miquelon">(UTC-03:00) Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
  <option value="America/Bahia">(UTC-03:00) Salvador</option>
  <option value="Etc/GMT+2">(UTC-02:00) Coordinated Universal Time-02</option>
  <option value="Atlantic/Azores">(UTC-01:00) Azores</option>
  <option value="Atlantic/Cape_Verde">(UTC-01:00) Cabo Verde Is.</option>
  <option value="Etc/UTC">(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time</option>
  <option value="Europe/London">(UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London</option>
  <option value="Atlantic/Reykjavik">(UTC+00:00) Monrovia, Reykjavik</option>
  <option value="Africa/Sao_Tome">(UTC+00:00) Sao Tome</option>
  <option value="Africa/Casablanca">(UTC+01:00) Casablanca</option>
  <option value="Europe/Berlin">(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna</option>
  <option value="Europe/Budapest">(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague</option>
  <option value="Europe/Paris">(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris</option>
  <option value="Europe/Warsaw">(UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb</option>
  <option value="Africa/Lagos">(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa</option>
  <option value="Asia/Amman">(UTC+02:00) Amman</option>
  <option value="Europe/Bucharest">(UTC+02:00) Athens, Bucharest</option>
  <option value="Asia/Beirut">(UTC+02:00) Beirut</option>
  <option value="Africa/Cairo">(UTC+02:00) Cairo</option>
  <option value="Europe/Chisinau">(UTC+02:00) Chisinau</option>
  <option value="Asia/Damascus">(UTC+02:00) Damascus</option>
  <option value="Asia/Hebron">(UTC+02:00) Gaza, Hebron</option>
  <option value="Africa/Johannesburg">(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria</option>
  <option value="Europe/Kiev">(UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius</option>
  <option value="Asia/Jerusalem">(UTC+02:00) Jerusalem</option>
  <option value="Europe/Kaliningrad">(UTC+02:00) Kaliningrad</option>
  <option value="Africa/Khartoum">(UTC+02:00) Khartoum</option>
  <option value="Africa/Tripoli">(UTC+02:00) Tripoli</option>
  <option value="Africa/Windhoek">(UTC+02:00) Windhoek</option>
  <option value="Asia/Baghdad">(UTC+03:00) Baghdad</option>
  <option value="Europe/Istanbul">(UTC+03:00) Istanbul</option>
  <option value="Asia/Riyadh">(UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh</option>
  <option value="Europe/Minsk">(UTC+03:00) Minsk</option>
  <option value="Europe/Moscow">(UTC+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg</option>
  <option value="Africa/Nairobi">(UTC+03:00) Nairobi</option>
  <option value="Asia/Tehran">(UTC+03:30) Tehran</option>
  <option value="Asia/Dubai">(UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat</option>
  <option value="Europe/Astrakhan">(UTC+04:00) Astrakhan, Ulyanovsk</option>
  <option value="Asia/Baku">(UTC+04:00) Baku</option>
  <option value="Europe/Samara">(UTC+04:00) Izhevsk, Samara</option>
  <option value="Indian/Mauritius">(UTC+04:00) Port Louis</option>
  <option value="Europe/Saratov">(UTC+04:00) Saratov</option>
  <option value="Asia/Tbilisi">(UTC+04:00) Tbilisi</option>
  <option value="Europe/Volgograd">(UTC+04:00) Volgograd</option>
  <option value="Asia/Yerevan">(UTC+04:00) Yerevan</option>
  <option value="Asia/Kabul">(UTC+04:30) Kabul</option>
  <option value="Asia/Tashkent">(UTC+05:00) Ashgabat, Tashkent</option>
  <option value="Asia/Yekaterinburg">(UTC+05:00) Ekaterinburg</option>
  <option value="Asia/Karachi">(UTC+05:00) Islamabad, Karachi</option>
  <option value="Asia/Qyzylorda">(UTC+05:00) Qyzylorda</option>
  <option value="Asia/Kolkata">(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi</option>
  <option value="Asia/Colombo">(UTC+05:30) Sri Jayawardenepura</option>
  <option value="Asia/Kathmandu">(UTC+05:45) Kathmandu</option>
  <option value="Asia/Almaty">(UTC+06:00) Astana</option>
  <option value="Asia/Dhaka">(UTC+06:00) Dhaka</option>
  <option value="Asia/Omsk">(UTC+06:00) Omsk</option>
  <option value="Asia/Yangon">(UTC+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)</option>
  <option value="Asia/Bangkok">(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta</option>
  <option value="Asia/Barnaul">(UTC+07:00) Barnaul, Gorno-Altaysk</option>
  <option value="Asia/Hovd">(UTC+07:00) Hovd</option>
  <option value="Asia/Krasnoyarsk">(UTC+07:00) Krasnoyarsk</option>
  <option value="Asia/Novosibirsk">(UTC+07:00) Novosibirsk</option>
  <option value="Asia/Tomsk">(UTC+07:00) Tomsk</option>
  <option value="Asia/Shanghai">(UTC+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi</option>
  <option value="Asia/Irkutsk">(UTC+08:00) Irkutsk</option>
  <option value="Asia/Singapore">(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore</option>
  <option value="Australia/Perth">(UTC+08:00) Perth</option>
  <option value="Asia/Taipei">(UTC+08:00) Taipei</option>
  <option value="Asia/Ulaanbaatar">(UTC+08:00) Ulaanbaatar</option>
  <option value="Australia/Eucla">(UTC+08:45) Eucla</option>
  <option value="Asia/Chita">(UTC+09:00) Chita</option>
  <option value="Asia/Tokyo">(UTC+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo</option>
  <option value="Asia/Pyongyang">(UTC+09:00) Pyongyang</option>
  <option value="Asia/Seoul">(UTC+09:00) Seoul</option>
  <option value="Asia/Yakutsk">(UTC+09:00) Yakutsk</option>
  <option value="Australia/Adelaide">(UTC+09:30) Adelaide</option>
  <option value="Australia/Darwin">(UTC+09:30) Darwin</option>
  <option value="Australia/Brisbane">(UTC+10:00) Brisbane</option>
  <option value="Australia/Sydney">(UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney</option>
  <option value="Pacific/Port_Moresby">(UTC+10:00) Guam, Port Moresby</option>
  <option value="Australia/Hobart">(UTC+10:00) Hobart</option>
  <option value="Asia/Vladivostok">(UTC+10:00) Vladivostok</option>
  <option value="Australia/Lord_Howe">(UTC+10:30) Lord Howe Island</option>
  <option value="Pacific/Bougainville">(UTC+11:00) Bougainville Island</option>
  <option value="Asia/Srednekolymsk">(UTC+11:00) Chokurdakh</option>
  <option value="Asia/Magadan">(UTC+11:00) Magadan</option>
  <option value="Pacific/Norfolk">(UTC+11:00) Norfolk Island</option>
  <option value="Asia/Sakhalin">(UTC+11:00) Sakhalin</option>
  <option value="Pacific/Guadalcanal">(UTC+11:00) Solomon Is., New Caledonia</option>
  <option value="Asia/Kamchatka">(UTC+12:00) Anadyr, Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky</option>
  <option value="Pacific/Auckland">(UTC+12:00) Auckland, Wellington</option>
  <option value="Etc/GMT-12">(UTC+12:00) Coordinated Universal Time+12</option>
  <option value="Pacific/Fiji">(UTC+12:00) Fiji</option>
  <option value="Pacific/Chatham">(UTC+12:45) Chatham Islands</option>
  <option value="Etc/GMT-13">(UTC+13:00) Coordinated Universal Time+13</option>
  <option value="Pacific/Tongatapu">(UTC+13:00) Nuku'alofa</option>
  <option value="Pacific/Apia">(UTC+13:00) Samoa</option>
  <option value="Pacific/Kiritimati">(UTC+14:00) Kiritimati Island</option>
</select>
```

Here is a modified version of the program that produces JSON instead:

```cs
var names = TZNames.GetDisplayNames("en-US", useIanaZoneIds: true);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(names, formatting: Formatting.Indented);
Console.Write(json);
```

```json
{
  "Etc/GMT+12": "(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West",
  "Etc/GMT+11": "(UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11",
  "America/Adak": "(UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands",
  "Pacific/Honolulu": "(UTC-10:00) Hawaii",
  "Pacific/Marquesas": "(UTC-09:30) Marquesas Islands",
  "America/Anchorage": "(UTC-09:00) Alaska",
  "Etc/GMT+9": "(UTC-09:00) Coordinated Universal Time-09",
  "America/Whitehorse": "(UTC-07:00) Yukon",
  "America/Tijuana": "(UTC-08:00) Baja California",
  "Etc/GMT+8": "(UTC-08:00) Coordinated Universal Time-08",
  "America/Los_Angeles": "(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
  "America/Phoenix": "(UTC-07:00) Arizona",
  "America/Chihuahua": "(UTC-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan",
  "America/Denver": "(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)",
  "America/Guatemala": "(UTC-06:00) Central America",
  "America/Chicago": "(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)",
  "Pacific/Easter": "(UTC-06:00) Easter Island",
  "America/Mexico_City": "(UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey",
  "America/Regina": "(UTC-06:00) Saskatchewan",
  "America/Bogota": "(UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco",
  "America/Cancun": "(UTC-05:00) Chetumal",
  "America/New_York": "(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
  "America/Port-au-Prince": "(UTC-05:00) Haiti",
  "America/Havana": "(UTC-05:00) Havana",
  "America/Indiana/Indianapolis": "(UTC-05:00) Indiana (East)",
  "America/Grand_Turk": "(UTC-05:00) Turks and Caicos",
  "America/Asuncion": "(UTC-04:00) Asuncion",
  "America/Halifax": "(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)",
  "America/Caracas": "(UTC-04:00) Caracas",
  "America/Cuiaba": "(UTC-04:00) Cuiaba",
  "America/La_Paz": "(UTC-04:00) Georgetown, La Paz, Manaus, San Juan",
  "America/Santiago": "(UTC-04:00) Santiago",
  "America/St_Johns": "(UTC-03:30) Newfoundland",
  "America/Araguaina": "(UTC-03:00) Araguaina",
  "America/Sao_Paulo": "(UTC-03:00) Brasilia",
  "America/Cayenne": "(UTC-03:00) Cayenne, Fortaleza",
  "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires": "(UTC-03:00) City of Buenos Aires",
  "America/Nuuk": "(UTC-03:00) Greenland",
  "America/Montevideo": "(UTC-03:00) Montevideo",
  "America/Punta_Arenas": "(UTC-03:00) Punta Arenas",
  "America/Miquelon": "(UTC-03:00) Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
  "America/Bahia": "(UTC-03:00) Salvador",
  "Etc/GMT+2": "(UTC-02:00) Coordinated Universal Time-02",
  "Atlantic/Azores": "(UTC-01:00) Azores",
  "Atlantic/Cape_Verde": "(UTC-01:00) Cabo Verde Is.",
  "Etc/UTC": "(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time",
  "Europe/London": "(UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London",
  "Atlantic/Reykjavik": "(UTC+00:00) Monrovia, Reykjavik",
  "Africa/Sao_Tome": "(UTC+00:00) Sao Tome",
  "Africa/Casablanca": "(UTC+01:00) Casablanca",
  "Europe/Berlin": "(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna",
  "Europe/Budapest": "(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague",
  "Europe/Paris": "(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris",
  "Europe/Warsaw": "(UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb",
  "Africa/Lagos": "(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa",
  "Asia/Amman": "(UTC+02:00) Amman",
  "Europe/Bucharest": "(UTC+02:00) Athens, Bucharest",
  "Asia/Beirut": "(UTC+02:00) Beirut",
  "Africa/Cairo": "(UTC+02:00) Cairo",
  "Europe/Chisinau": "(UTC+02:00) Chisinau",
  "Asia/Damascus": "(UTC+02:00) Damascus",
  "Asia/Hebron": "(UTC+02:00) Gaza, Hebron",
  "Africa/Johannesburg": "(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria",
  "Europe/Kiev": "(UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius",
  "Asia/Jerusalem": "(UTC+02:00) Jerusalem",
  "Europe/Kaliningrad": "(UTC+02:00) Kaliningrad",
  "Africa/Khartoum": "(UTC+02:00) Khartoum",
  "Africa/Tripoli": "(UTC+02:00) Tripoli",
  "Africa/Windhoek": "(UTC+02:00) Windhoek",
  "Asia/Baghdad": "(UTC+03:00) Baghdad",
  "Europe/Istanbul": "(UTC+03:00) Istanbul",
  "Asia/Riyadh": "(UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh",
  "Europe/Minsk": "(UTC+03:00) Minsk",
  "Europe/Moscow": "(UTC+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg",
  "Africa/Nairobi": "(UTC+03:00) Nairobi",
  "Asia/Tehran": "(UTC+03:30) Tehran",
  "Asia/Dubai": "(UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat",
  "Europe/Astrakhan": "(UTC+04:00) Astrakhan, Ulyanovsk",
  "Asia/Baku": "(UTC+04:00) Baku",
  "Europe/Samara": "(UTC+04:00) Izhevsk, Samara",
  "Indian/Mauritius": "(UTC+04:00) Port Louis",
  "Europe/Saratov": "(UTC+04:00) Saratov",
  "Asia/Tbilisi": "(UTC+04:00) Tbilisi",
  "Europe/Volgograd": "(UTC+04:00) Volgograd",
  "Asia/Yerevan": "(UTC+04:00) Yerevan",
  "Asia/Kabul": "(UTC+04:30) Kabul",
  "Asia/Tashkent": "(UTC+05:00) Ashgabat, Tashkent",
  "Asia/Yekaterinburg": "(UTC+05:00) Ekaterinburg",
  "Asia/Karachi": "(UTC+05:00) Islamabad, Karachi",
  "Asia/Qyzylorda": "(UTC+05:00) Qyzylorda",
  "Asia/Kolkata": "(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi",
  "Asia/Colombo": "(UTC+05:30) Sri Jayawardenepura",
  "Asia/Kathmandu": "(UTC+05:45) Kathmandu",
  "Asia/Almaty": "(UTC+06:00) Astana",
  "Asia/Dhaka": "(UTC+06:00) Dhaka",
  "Asia/Omsk": "(UTC+06:00) Omsk",
  "Asia/Yangon": "(UTC+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)",
  "Asia/Bangkok": "(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta",
  "Asia/Barnaul": "(UTC+07:00) Barnaul, Gorno-Altaysk",
  "Asia/Hovd": "(UTC+07:00) Hovd",
  "Asia/Krasnoyarsk": "(UTC+07:00) Krasnoyarsk",
  "Asia/Novosibirsk": "(UTC+07:00) Novosibirsk",
  "Asia/Tomsk": "(UTC+07:00) Tomsk",
  "Asia/Shanghai": "(UTC+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi",
  "Asia/Irkutsk": "(UTC+08:00) Irkutsk",
  "Asia/Singapore": "(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore",
  "Australia/Perth": "(UTC+08:00) Perth",
  "Asia/Taipei": "(UTC+08:00) Taipei",
  "Asia/Ulaanbaatar": "(UTC+08:00) Ulaanbaatar",
  "Australia/Eucla": "(UTC+08:45) Eucla",
  "Asia/Chita": "(UTC+09:00) Chita",
  "Asia/Tokyo": "(UTC+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo",
  "Asia/Pyongyang": "(UTC+09:00) Pyongyang",
  "Asia/Seoul": "(UTC+09:00) Seoul",
  "Asia/Yakutsk": "(UTC+09:00) Yakutsk",
  "Australia/Adelaide": "(UTC+09:30) Adelaide",
  "Australia/Darwin": "(UTC+09:30) Darwin",
  "Australia/Brisbane": "(UTC+10:00) Brisbane",
  "Australia/Sydney": "(UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney",
  "Pacific/Port_Moresby": "(UTC+10:00) Guam, Port Moresby",
  "Australia/Hobart": "(UTC+10:00) Hobart",
  "Asia/Vladivostok": "(UTC+10:00) Vladivostok",
  "Australia/Lord_Howe": "(UTC+10:30) Lord Howe Island",
  "Pacific/Bougainville": "(UTC+11:00) Bougainville Island",
  "Asia/Srednekolymsk": "(UTC+11:00) Chokurdakh",
  "Asia/Magadan": "(UTC+11:00) Magadan",
  "Pacific/Norfolk": "(UTC+11:00) Norfolk Island",
  "Asia/Sakhalin": "(UTC+11:00) Sakhalin",
  "Pacific/Guadalcanal": "(UTC+11:00) Solomon Is., New Caledonia",
  "Asia/Kamchatka": "(UTC+12:00) Anadyr, Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky",
  "Pacific/Auckland": "(UTC+12:00) Auckland, Wellington",
  "Etc/GMT-12": "(UTC+12:00) Coordinated Universal Time+12",
  "Pacific/Fiji": "(UTC+12:00) Fiji",
  "Pacific/Chatham": "(UTC+12:45) Chatham Islands",
  "Etc/GMT-13": "(UTC+13:00) Coordinated Universal Time+13",
  "Pacific/Tongatapu": "(UTC+13:00) Nuku'alofa",
  "Pacific/Apia": "(UTC+13:00) Samoa",
  "Pacific/Kiritimati": "(UTC+14:00) Kiritimati Island"
}
```

You can uses these lists from HTML/JS, or anywhere really.  I will consider making a more full-featured JS library at some point.